# Trouble getting <p> and <ul> on the same height

Tags: html, css

I have recently started with web development, and I have this issue: I can't get my h1 and my ul on the same height in the header. I tried putting margin on the ul, then on the li's or to put padding on it. Same with the h1. I know it is probably a simple problem, but I can't figure out how to solve it. Here is the HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body header {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 0px 3px 10px; 
    margin: 0px;
}

body header h1 {
    display: inline;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 40px 5px 0px 0px; 
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

body header ul {
    display: inline;
}

body header ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 10px;
}

body header ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; 
    background: #222;
}

body header ul li a:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/Skulldozer%201.1.css">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header> 
        <h1>Example</h1>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Stories</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </header> 

    <div>
        
    </div>


    <script src="scripts/Skulldozer%201.1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't specify the body element in every single CSS statement, it looks weird and is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `vertical-align: bottom;` which I believe solves your issue.

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 0px 3px 10px; 
    margin: 0px;
}

header h1 {
    display: inline;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 40px 5px 0px 0px; 
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

header ul {
    display: inline;
}

header ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 10px;
}

header ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; 
    background: #222;
}

header ul li a:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/Skulldozer%201.1.css">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header> 
        <h1>Example</h1>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Stories</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </header> 

    <div>
        
    </div>


    <script src="scripts/Skulldozer%201.1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```